# How to determine neighbours in a stack

Tags: java, stack, multidimensional-array

Basically, I'm making a maze with a random generation, following the logic here: http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/

They say that I should try determining my neighbours whilst in a stack, but I'm stuck on the how. I decided that I'd try their logic, but use a 2D array instead. However, that brings other issues with the whole relooping: how do I revisit a cell or otherwise remove it in a 2d array?

My code so far. I have an issue here as well: I'm trying to let a Field paint itself on the panel, but it's not working: I only get a black bg color and no lines / squares.

So, my question is: how to best determine neighbours and create the random maze with what I have

AND

Why is my basic field of squares not getting drawn?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

/* @author chris */

public class Field {

    private int   fieldData, 
                  fieldSize;

    public Field( int fieldData , int fieldSize ) {

        this.fieldData = fieldData;
        this.fieldSize = fieldSize;

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public Field() {

    }

    public void paint(int rows , int cols , Graphics g) {


        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        int x2 = fieldSize;
        int y2 = fieldSize;

        for( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ ) {

            for( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++ ) {

                g.drawLine( x , y , x , y2 ); // n
                g.drawLine( x , y2 , x2 , y2 ); // e 
                g.drawLine( x2 , y , x2 , y2 ); // s
                g.drawLine( x , y , x2 , y ); // w

                if( j != cols-1 ) {

                    x = x+fieldSize;
                    x2 = x2+fieldSize;

                }else { 

                    y = y+fieldSize;
                    y2 = y2+fieldSize;
                    x = 0;
                    x2 = fieldSize;

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is my panel's code. The makeItAMaze method is where I'm stuck at.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/* @author chris */

public class LevelPanel extends JPanel {

private final int rows = 20;
private final int cols = 40;
private final int fieldSize = 20;

private Field[][] map = new Field[cols][rows];



LevelPanel() {

    setBackground( Color.BLACK );

 }


public void generateMap() {

    for ( int j = 0 ; j < rows ; j++ ) { // 2d array
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < cols ; i++ ) {

            // Determine position, give appropriate border
            if( j > 0 && i > 0 && j < cols && i < rows ) { 

                // North, east, south, west for backtrack, solution, border, wall
                Field f = new Field(0000000000001111, fieldSize ); // center
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( i == 0 && j == 0 ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000010011111, fieldSize); // nw
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( j > 1 && i == 0 && j < cols ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000010001111, fieldSize ); // n
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( i == 0 && j == cols ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000011001111, fieldSize ); // ne
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( i > 0 && j == cols && i < rows ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000001001111, fieldSize ); // e
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( j == cols && i == rows ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000001101111, fieldSize ); // se
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( j > 0 && j < cols && i == rows ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000000101111, fieldSize ); // s
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( j == 0 && i == rows ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000000111111, fieldSize ); // sw
                f = map[i][j];

            }else if( j == 0 && i > 0 && i < rows ) {

                Field f = new Field(0000000000011111, fieldSize ); // w
                f = map[i][j];

            }
        }
    }

    makeItAMaze();

} // ends generateMap()

@Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

     super.paintComponent(g);

     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;

     int x2 = fieldSize;
     int y2 = fieldSize;

     for( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++ ) {

        for( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; j++ ) {

            // TODO: need to draw from a Field

            Field f = new Field();
            f.paint( rows , cols , g );

        }
    }

} // ends paintComponent


public void makeItAMaze() {

    Random r = new Random();

    int totalFields = rows * cols;
    int fieldsTogo = 0;

    while ( fieldsTogo < totalFields ) {



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been some time and no one has given a proper answer, so I'll post the solutions I've found.

The solution to my first question is that in order to save neighbors, you shouldn't use a stack, but use a HashMap. You generally want to know something about how to find the neighbor from the current location (direction to move in) which you can use as a key in the HashMap.

As for the second painting issue. In the code, I start by making a new Field instance, again, whereas I already made a dozen in the earlier method. Better practice would be to create a bunch of fields in a loop with default values and then change the created fields in another method / loop.

The actual painting error occurs because paintComponent is the first method that gets initialized when I create this Class. This results in me basically trying to draw a Field which simply does not yet exist or does not yet have any data. The solution is to move the initialization of the fields to the constructor, instead of a method.

Answer (score 0):

You set the background color, but I don't see where you set the foreground color when you draw the lines. It probably is drawing them in black.

Comment: Java automatically paints in a white foreground color if the background is black.